# INSERT multiple rows from another CTE inserts

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

```
WITH wms_monitor_log AS (
INSERT INTO
    data_monitoring_wms (doctype)
VALUES
    ('Income') RETURNING id), 


wms_monitor_log_dale as (
INSERT into
    data_monitoring_wms_dale (fk1187, fk1158)
SELECT
    wml.id,
    1052
FROM
    wms_monitor_log wml RETURNING fk1187 as log_id) 


INSERT into data_monitoring_wms_dale (fk1187, fk1184)
SELECT    wmldale.log_id,    100 FROM wms_monitor_log_dale wmldale 
union
SELECT   wmldale.log_id,     200 FROM wms_monitor_log_dale wmldale
union
SELECT   wmldale.log_id,     300 FROM wms_monitor_log_dale wmldale
```

I would guess, the wms_monitor_log_dale CTE will be called 3 times. But actually it's only called once.
Is it because of some kind of plan optimalization in postgress or the result is ensured to be the same every time?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) "*Data-modifying statements in WITH are executed **exactly once***"

Comment: Also if relying on a foreign key from said CTEs, they modify the data concurrently and therefore the order in which they operate is unpredictable